# Where can I find the commands for the main menu items?

Tags: 11.10, autostart

How to find out full path (with options) to installed applications (such as Skype, Firefox, Chromium etc.) in Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric for adding them to autostart?

Comment: Thank you for answers, but it seems my question was wrong. Let me try one more time =)
I remember that for example Firefox has command like "firefox %u" (or something like this). And I'd like to know where in Oneiric I can find commands for main menu items?

Comment: I tried to mention Main Menu in my answer. You can find command name options there.

Comment: I found it!

/usr/share/applications

Thanks to all and me =)

Comment: And btw there isn't MainMenu in Dash in Oneiric. I don't know why...

Comment: Yes, this is an alternative way also. You must install **alacarte** package to have Main Menu.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this changes according to installation, but generally you can add applications with its command names such as skype, firefox, chromium-browser etc. You don't need the full path if those files in your path.

But, if you are looking for a way to see the full command name line, install alacarte:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Start it with typing "Main Menu" via dash. You can find applications and their command line parts in suitable sections.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and  type `which <space>` and  the executable filename of the application to find it.

For example, The main executable/binary file of Firefox is `firefox`, so open a terminal and type in `which firefox` to find the absolute path to Firefox.